# Some problems with passing arguments to overloaded functions

Tags: java, arguments, overloading

```
package java_coding;

public class String_Null {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String_Null string_Null = new String_Null();
    string_Null.method(null);
}

public void method(String string) {
    System.out.println("String");
}

public void method( Object object) {

    System.out.println("Object");
}


}
```

The result is String. Explain why?

Comment: If you wanted "Object", you'd have to cast the `null` to something incompatible with `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Because *the most specific* method is chosen, the most specific is `String` (compared to `Object`). This is in the JLS btw... I'll dig this up shortly.

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run- time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

Comment: Could this be a comment??

Comment: It could; but it is the correct answer.

Comment: @MadMan. It actually is the answer. There's really no other reason

Comment: @Eugene added the next sentence too, because I think it is useful to understand what "most specific" actually means.

Comment: @AndyTurner I wanted to say thank you, but you you *were not present* here to tag. thank you

Comment: got it...!! the quotes says it all..!!